# Какой запрос SQL эффективней, с подзапросом или LEFT JOIN с GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, h2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой запрос эффективней (выполнится за наименьшее время/потребит меньше ресурсов CPU/Memory)?

Запрос 1:

```
SELECT c.ID,
  (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE),0)
    FROM REQUESTS r
    WHERE r.CAMPAIGN_ID = c.ID
  ) crt,
  c.ACTION, c.STATUS
FROM CAMPAIGNS c
WHERE c.ACTION = 'RUN';
```

Запрос 2:

```
SELECT c.ID, IFNULL(SUM(r.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE),0) crt,
  c.ACTION, c.STATUS
FROM CAMPAIGNS c
LEFT JOIN REQUESTS r ON c.ID = r.CAMPAIGN_ID
WHERE c.ACTION = 'RUN'
GROUP BY c.ID;
```

**UPD.**
База данных - H2 (ver.1.4.196).
План запроса 1:

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    (SELECT
        IFNULL(SUM(R.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE), 0)
    FROM PUBLIC.REQUESTS R
        /* PUBLIC.FK7P4151Y6F7SQNNI0I64LC02JF_INDEX_1: CAMPAIGN_ID = C.ID */
    WHERE R.CAMPAIGN_ID = C.ID) AS CRT,
    C.ACTION,
    C.STATUS
FROM PUBLIC.CAMPAIGNS C
    /* PUBLIC.CAMPAIGNS.tableScan */
WHERE C.ACTION = 'RUN'
```

План запроса 2:

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    IFNULL(SUM(R.CAMPAIGN_CPM_RATE), 0) AS CRT,
    C.ACTION,
    C.STATUS
FROM PUBLIC.CAMPAIGNS C
    /* PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_A */
    /* WHERE C.ACTION = 'RUN'
    */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.REQUESTS R
    /* PUBLIC.FK7P4151Y6F7SQNNI0I64LC02JF_INDEX_1: CAMPAIGN_ID = C.ID */
    ON C.ID = R.CAMPAIGN_ID
WHERE C.ACTION = 'RUN'
GROUP BY C.ID
/* group sorted */
```

Comment: Посмотрите план. Они, с некоторой вероятностью, будут выполняться одинаково.

Comment: Вопрос не имеет абсолютно никакого смысла без указания конкретной СУБД конкретной версии. В абстрактном SQL нет ничего о том как имено запросы СУБД должна выполнять, только о том, какой результат какая конструкция должна иметь.

Comment: @PashaPash добавил информацию о планах запроса

Comment: @Мелкий добавил информацию о БД